# Ruby on Rails 3, incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, internationalization, character-encoding

I've got some troubles with the couple Rails 3.0.1, Ruby 1.9.2 and my website localization.

The problem is quite simple, i've got something like that in a view :

```
f.input :zip_code, :label => I18n.t('labels.zip_code')
```

and a es.yml file :

```
es:
  labels:
    zip_code: "Este código postal no es valido."
```

There are no troubles with the en.yml file (it's pure ASCII) but when the website is set with `i18n.locale == 'es'` I get this error :

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

I have been looking around for quite a while but didn't found a way to use my UTF-8 translation files.

Did some knows how to make it works ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is sort of off topic, but Ryan Bates just posted a railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) on i18n today. If anyone sees this comment the week of 3/6/2011, then in a way this comment is sort of relevant to you.

Comment: James has a pretty nice tutorial on his blog, coverings almost all aspects of string encoding in Ruby 1.9. To understand what "external" and "internal" encoding mean, read it at: http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings

Comment: Here's an awesome explanation of encoding on Rails: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Ok so problem solved after some hours of googling...

There was actually two bugs in my code. The first one was a file encoding error and the second was the problem with the MySQL Data base configuration.

First, to solve the error caused by MySQL I used this two articles :

http://www.dotkam.com/2008/09/14/configure-rails-and-mysql-to-support-utf-8/

http://www.rorra.com.ar/2010/07/30/rails-3-mysql-and-utf-8/

Second, to solve the file encoding problem I added these 2 lines in my config/environment.rb

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Hopefully this will help someone :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Had the same problem, and I had everything alright except I was using the mysql gem instead of mysql2.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, but I only noticed it when a source code file had a funny ' character in it.   I had both mysql and mysql2 gems in my gemfile, I had to remove the old mysql gem. (and alter my database.yml file)

Comment: I am getting same error but when using rails cache. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114872/rails-character-encoding-issue-while-using-cache

Comment: AHHHH!  Thanks!  Also have to upgrade to mysql2 gem and update database.yml accordingly.  Worked for me too.

Comment: I am getting this error on Ruby 2.0.0p576 (but not 2.0.0 p481) when putting a string to a Protocol Buffers message.

Answer (score 23):

I solved most of the problems by combining many solutions:

- Make sure `application.rb` has this line: `config.encoding = "utf-8"`.
- Make sure you are using 'mysql2' gem
- Putting `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of any file containing utf-8 characters.
- Add the following two lines above the `<App Name>::Application.initialize!` line in `environment.rb`:

  ```
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
  ```

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/06/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii.html

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4804802/72176 has a good way to add the suggested `# encoding: UTF-8` to all ruby files.

Comment: I added just `# encoding: utf-8` on first of my controller and any thing is good. I have Rails 3.2.7 on Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: A word of advice: mysql2 gem is only suitable for MRI Ruby, dont use it with jruby.

Comment: this helped me, especially the Encoding.default_external part

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in your `config/application.rb`. Also, your example translation file doesn't match the key you're searching for (`com_name` and `first_name`) but I suppose that could just be a typo.

Comment: Oups sry about the exemple. I just took a bad one with no UTF-8 char :p Whatever... i do have config.encoding = "utf-8" in my application.rb and Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8 in my environment.rb. Thanks :)

Comment: It can be very hard to determine where the incompatible data is coming from.. I'd try bisecting your templates in terms of data source.. So try a template with only I18n stuff, another with only data from the database, same for your cache if you have one, etc. If you're using MySQL then try switching to the mysql2 driver and make sure that config/database.yml specifies encoding: utf-8

Comment: Thanks :) Ok so, I checked and can get and display i18n strings from the MySQL DB. But i can't get strings from the i18n file and so far, I don't use cache.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `es.yml` file was saved as UTF-8?

If you're on Windows, use http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using this unpack function helped me sort this out finally, try this if you get the can't convert error message:

```
myString.unpack('U*').pack('U*')
```

Comment: It sounds a little bit CPU expensive and painful if you have to do it on all the strings...

Comment: Wish i could have got any other options to stop this error, but they didn't work for me. I haven't noticed any cpu increase,

Comment: know what I'll try the top answer solution again lateron just because and report back

Comment: Is your problem comming from characters in the DB or in the view files?

Comment: hey haven't found time :/ I've run into this problem while scraping really and only then ~ so before it hits any database.

Comment: That might help, make sure you have the meta in your html header (haml in my case): %meta{'http-equiv' => 'content-type', 'content' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
That way the browser knows that this is utf-8.