# Parsing YAML Rails fails with UTF8 problems, IRB does fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, yaml

i currently try to import some XML via XMLSimple in my RoR-3 App.

on 1 position, that XML stores a YAML-Structure. Dont slap me, i did not create the xml ;)

now that i have it stored in a variable, lets say **yamldata**, i want to parse its content.

so i do:

```
chunks = YAML::load yamldata
```

and thats pretty it.

when i now echo these chunks-values to console, it get this:

- BÃ¼lach vert

what i wanted to have is:

- Bülach vert

when i use exact same sourcecode in IRB, i actually get this 'ü' instead of 'Ã¼'.

i really dont know what to do here.

---

my Gemfile:

## cat Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'activerecord', :require => "active_record"
gem 'xml-simple'
gem 'hpricot'
```

---

ruby -v:
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

i`d be happy with any idea.

Note: i echo these values before!! i store them into a model, so i guess that its not a sql-related issue - however, db-encoding is utf8 too.

any idea? Thanks!

thanks to the helpers! :)

Comment: did you try magic quote inside the corresponded controller ? Put this at the top "# coding: utf-8"

Comment: shebang already in there - same effect :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found that irb does use Syck, rails Psych.
so i guess this is the main difference... will research more..

## SOLUTION:

```
 require 'yaml'
 YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

into boot.rb and BAM!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help you:

[Ruby on Rails 3, incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT with i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188677/ruby-on-rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit-with-i18n)

He states that he could solve a similar problem by configuring this:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

on config/environment.rb

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for that hint - good to know that.
unfortunately it did not solve the problem. i pleaced it in environment.rb + executed it in console too, very same result. :/