# How is the character ± invalid when seeding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Why am I not allow to rake my seeds.rb file when I have the following `±` character somewhere in my code?

Example:

```
:product_name => 'lenovo G570 NoteBook 15.6" 3GB Memory DDR3 500GB HDD DVD±R/RW'
```

While its running I suddenly get:

```
Invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
...3GB Memory DDR3 500GB HDD DVD┬▒R/RW',
...
```

Taking away the character solves everything, I even can add it normally in my application and it ends up in the database with all characters and no problems.

Why is this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you should ensure that `seeds.rb` is saved with the correct encoding. Presumably UTF-8. Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188677/ruby-on-rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit-with-i18/6916708#6916708).