# Action Controller: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8

I have a text file that has some ® (Registered Trade Mark) symbols in it.  The file is in UTF-8.

I'm trying to import this file and populate a MySQL database using Rails 3.  The DB appears to be setup fine to take UTF-8

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field       | Type         | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id          | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NULL            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| title       | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| translation | text         | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created_at  | datetime     | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Yet, when I try to do this:

```
trans_file = params[:descriptions] #coming from file_field_tag
trans = trans_file.read.split("\r\n")
trans.each do |tran|
  ttl = ''
  desc = ''
  tran.split(']=').each do |title|
    if title =~ /\[/ #it's the title
      ttl = title.sub('[','')
    else
      desc = title.gsub('FFF', "\r\n")
    end
  end
  @current_user.cd_translations.build(title: ttl, translation: desc).save
```

I'm getting the error "Action Controller: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8".

I'm using the utf-8 encoding in my application.rb file, and I'm using the mysql2 gem.

If I remove the Registered Trade Mark character, the error goes away.  But it's not really an option to strip it out of the incoming text.

I tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215676/102372, but that didn't make any difference.

Stack trace:

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `block in update_cd_translations'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:15:in `each'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:15:in `update_cd_translations'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you show how you're opening / reading from the file? Have you set any of the default encodings? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: What is the encoding of that controller file? You can see what ruby thinks it is by checking the encoding of any of the string literals in it

Comment: It's US-ASCII, but trying Lictamberg's answer below doesn't change the exception I'm getting.

Comment: What encoding does ruby think the strings coming from your uploaded file are?

Comment: Ah, it's showing ASCII-8BIT, is there a way to convert?

Comment: If you know the encoding, force_encoding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that ruby thinks that the encoding of the uploaded file is ascii-8bit (that is to say binary).

If you know the encoding of the file, you can use `force_encoding!` to change the encoding of the string (without transcoding). If you're not always going to be sure of the encoding of the file, the `charguess` gem can be used to guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
```

at the beginnig of each file, which is included in the whole process