# I18n special characters in page title

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm coding a rails app, and I have a problem with the title's page :

In my `config/locales/fr.yml` I have this : `fr:product:edit: "Modification de l'objet"`

And in my `/app/views/products/edit.html.erb` I have this : `<title><%= t('product.edit') %></title>`

And when I render the page, it gives me this : `Modification de l&#39;objet.`

Do you know what's wrong with it ?

I tried to add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the head of my HTML, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188677/ruby-on-rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit-with-i18) but it didn't worked for me...

Comment: Weird. Can you try using `<%= raw(I18n.t('product.edit')) %>` ?

Comment: Yes it's working ! Thank you ! You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<%= raw(I18n.t('product.edit')) %>` to avoid this. Be aware though, that the code won't be escaped. When using `raw` you have to be sure there's no way to inject malicious code in the string.

Comment: In this case you're reading data from a file you trust os it's quite ok. However, don't use it to display strings that may have been written or modified by your users. `raw @user.name` would be dangerous, as someone could inject some malicious code in the name field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can tell you where `l&#'39` is coming from... 
Hopefuly then you can find a solution on how to fix it.

Open up notepad and holddown the Alt key and press 39 see what character appears ??

You notice you get the `'` character when you type that number so after compling you code seems to look at `l'objet` as `l And #39`

So I think there is as you are poinitg out some sort language issues and the characters are represented. You might be able to reverse this to solve your problem.

Sorry this is all I had.

Comment: I believe that if you just type &#39; instead of ' that should get rid of the problem... Have you tried it already? Basicaly reverse engineer it. Does that work?

Comment: Yes I tried too, and it didn't worked :-( Thanks for the idea though :-)

Comment: Ah OK, Sorry couldnt be more help. It must have something to do with how that character gets interpreted through HTML so there must be a different charset or a different content tag or something ....