# export to excel french character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel

I have the following method on on my action to export to excel a list of user:

```
def users_report
    @users = Kid.where(confirmation_token: nil).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    @userxls = Kid.where(confirmation_token: nil)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xls { send_data @userxls.to_csv({col_sep: "\t"}) }
    end
end
```

On my model the to_csv method:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << ["Name", "Surname", "E-mail", "Age", "School", "Class", "Native Language", "Practised Language", "Conversations same Native", "Convserations different Native", "Message same Native", "Message different Native", "Posts", "Clossed/Finished calls", "Missed calls", "Connections per Week", "Nb of foreign friends", "Nb of friends same country", "Activation Date", "Email Parent", "Parent Activated"]
        kids = Array.new
        all.each do |kid|
            if kid.user_role != "admin"
                k   = Array.new
                kid.name = kid.name rescue "No name"
                k << kid.name
                kid.surname = kid.surname rescue "No surname"
                k << kid.surname
                kid.email = kid.email rescue "No email"
                k << kid.email
                k << kid.age rescue "No age"
                if !kid.school.nil?
                    k << kid.school.name
                else
                    k << "No School"
                end
                if kid.courses.empty?
                    k << "No Courses"
                else
                    k << kid.courses.first.name
                end

                if !kid.native_languages.empty?
                    languages = Array.new
                    kid.native_languages.each do |lang|
                        languages << Language.find(lang).name
                    end
                    k << languages
                else
                    k << "No native language"
                end
                if !kid.practice_languages.empty?
                    languages = Array.new
                    kid.practice_languages.each do |lang|
                        languages << Language.find(lang).name
                    end
                    k << languages
                else
                    k << "No practise language"
                end

                k << kid.number_of_native_conversations rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_foreign_conversations rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_native_messages rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_foreign_messages rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_activity_posts rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_finished_closed_calls rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_missed_calls rescue "0"
                k << kid.avg_of_connections_week rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_foreign_friends rescue "0"
                k << kid.number_of_friends_same_country rescue "0"
                k << kid.confirmed_at.try(:strftime, "%d/%m/%Y") rescue "0"
                k << kid.tutor.email rescue "No parent email"
                k << kid.tutor.confirmed? rescue "No parent email"

                kids << k
            end
        end
        kids.each do |k|
            csv << k
        end
  end
end
```

But on my excel file I'm getting names like JÃ©rÃ´me instead of Jérôme. I tried:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

on my view also tried for every field

```
.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

But I still have this problem. Please I really need help with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188677/ruby-on-rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit-with-i18

Comment: Thanks pavan, but it won't

Answer (score 1):

`CVS::generate` understands an option `:encoding` (see [Ruby API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate)).

So use

```
format.xls { send_data @userxls.to_csv({col_sep: "\t", encoding: 'UTF-8'}) }
```

You may also think about separating representation and business logic. I use `csv_builder` that provides views like `user_report.csv.csvbuilder` to define the csv output.

`cvs_builder` uses the instance variable `@encoding` to specify the output character encoding.

**Edit**

It seems, like your generated csv is already encoded in UTF-8 but you read it as if it were ISO-8859-1 aka. LATIN-1.
You may want to try to generate the csv in `LATIN-1` as excel has issues importing UTF-8 csv files.
Depending on the Ruby or Rails version, you have to use `ISO-8859-1` instead of `LATIN-1`.

Comment: Thanks Martin M 
Now I getting this error: code converter not found (US-ASCII to ISO-8859-1:UTF-8) I changed my model code to CSV.generate(options, encoding: "ISO-8859-1:UTF-8") do |csv|

Comment: you just have to specify the output encoding `encoding: 'ISO-8859-1'`. But why are your strings `US-ASCII`?

Comment: I'm not :( the first line on my model is # encoding: utf-8, but I'm specifying US-ASCII in the app

Comment: you may want to read http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/ about encoding in Ruby

Comment: Hi @Jean. How did you solve this issue? I'm having the exact same problem